# Is there a way of capturing IFRAME context in Selenium By locators (or alternatives)?

Tags: java, selenium

I am writing automated tests for web applications using **Selenium 3.141.59** and **Java 8**. My general strategy for tracking elements of interest *(landmarks & interactive elements)* involves setting up a hierarchy of interfaces, each containing one or more **By** locators and/or subinterfaces, each interface representing an area within the application, *(e.g. the login screen.)*

The application under test (**AUT**) is a cloud-based app that makes annoyingly extensive use of **IFRAME**'s. While **switchTo()** generally serves me well, the only association between an element of interest and its parent **IFRAME** that I have, at present, is laid out within the test code itself. If I inadvertently fail to precede my wait with the appropriate **switchTo()**, my element never gets found. Fair enough. To mitigate this problem, I'm trying to improve my metadata by capturing the additional piece of context *(parent **IFRAME**)* along with each By locator, to help bulletproof my location process.

My first thought is that instead of defining constants consisting of simple By locators, one might create a composite class, a duple consisting of one field locating the element of interest, and another locating its parent frame.

But before I head blindly down that path, I thought I might seek advice from the community. *What are your thoughts/suggestions?*